# Multiple content length headers and multiple transfer encoding headers

Tags: http

If there are multiple content length headers, should I

1. fail (I don't think so?)
2. use the first one,
3. use the last one

Then I have the same question for transfer_encoding header too.  I think with transfer_encoding we are supposed to use the last one.

then, same question for 'Host' header as well.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Content-Length` is a single-value header. Usually the last header would have authority; however [RFC 7230, section 3.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2) states:

> If a message is received that has multiple Content-Length header fields with field-values consisting of the same decimal value, or a single Content-Length header field with a field value containing a list of identical decimal values (e.g., "Content-Length: 42, 42"), indicating that duplicate Content-Length header fields have been generated or combined by an upstream message processor, then the recipient MUST either reject the message as invalid or replace the duplicated field-values with a single valid Content-Length field containing that decimal value prior to determining the message body length or forwarding the message.

`Transfer-Encoding` is a different matter as it is containing a *list*. There can be multiple ones and all are valid. The important thing here is that applied encodings have to be listed in the order in which they have been applied. E.g. if content has been gzipped and then chunk-encoded, the headers have to look like

```
Transfer-Encoding: gzip, chunked
```

or

```
Transfer-Encoding: gzip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: "So semantically the last one is overriding any former headers." -- nobody has defined that. You could also say "any duplicates are ignored"

Comment: @JulianReschke "any duplicates are ignored" that really isn't the same. The way I have handled such situations in the past has been to ignore all previous headers, effectively letting the last one have authority. Updated my answer, btw.

Comment: that was my point; using the last one isn't any more obvious than using the first one (or a random one ftm)

Comment: @JulianReschke: idk, letting the last header "count" always struck me as intuitively right. I also *think* I saw something like that being mentioned in an older RFC … So I'll take your word for that until I find that passage again.

Answer (score 3):

WRT Content-Length: yes, you actually MUST fail (unless both values are the same, in which case you MAY pick one). See RFC 7230.

"Transfer-Encoding" is different in that it allows multiple values; so you'll have to process them all in order.